# using same screen with different configurations

Tags: android, design-patterns

My Android application has some screens that have some configurations that depends of specific parameters to determine what is going to be shown on the screen, like: Showing or not some fields, changing position on screen of some fields, changing components types. I am using view helper pattern for each combination, because I don´t want to add lots of if conditions on the view helper of the activity. I have tried to create a factory of view helpers that, depending of configuration, returns the respective view helper that configures the activity according to what I need. But I have some screens that might have more than 10 configurations. Considering that the number of possibilities follows the 2 pow n, which n is the number of configurations, in the previous sittuation, I would need to create 1024 view helpers - one for each possibility, which is clearly not a good idea. On the other hand, using the conditionals ifs, it would be very difficult for maintaining the project.

I would like some suggestions on what can be considered a good practice to this case. If possible, with examples of design patterns that can be used in this sittuation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use of [Strategy Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern)?

```
class MainApp
{
   static void Main()
   {
      Manager mgr;

      mgr = new Manager(new AboutPage());
      mgr.Configure();

      mgr = new Manager(new ProfilePage());
      mgr.Configure();
   }
}

abstract class BlogPage
{
   public abstract void ShowHideElement();
}

class AboutPage : BlogPage
{
   public override void ShowHideElement()
   {
       // Do some configuration here (hide / show element)
   }
}

class ProfilePage : BlogPage
{
   public override void ShowHideElement()
   {
      // Do some configuration here (hide / show element)
   }
}

class Manager
{
   private BlogPage _page;

   public Manager(BlogPage page)
   {
      this._page = page;
   }

   public void Configure()
   {
      _page.ShowHideElement();
   }
}
```

Thank you,